# Errors were encountered while processing: mount

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, mount, dpkg

When I try to `sudo apt-get upgrade` on my Ubuntu 16.04 I consistently get the following error:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package mount (--configure): package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
mount
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: ... *you should reinstall it before attempting configuration* - Did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to "reinstall" the "mount" package by doing: 
`sudo apt --reinstall mount`;

then:

`sudo apt upgrade`